# Visual Basic: How to include the output of a function within another function

Tags: vb.net, function, user-defined-functions

I would like to create two functions in VB.NET, one of which will calculate the area, and the other function will get the total price by multiplying the area by the user's entered price. Is there a way that I can include the output of one function inside another? My program will not compile currently, as I believe my logic is off. Thanks!

```
Public Function area(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    area = Val(enteredLength) * Val(enteredWidth)
End Function

Public Function totalPrice(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    totalPrice = Val(area) * Val(enteredPrice)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function and use the returned value as part of the calculation, like this:

```
Public Function area(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double) As Double
    Return enteredLength * enteredWidth
End Function

Public Function totalPrice(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double) As Double
    Return area(enteredLength, enteredWidth) * enteredPrice
End Function
```

It is not necessary to use the `Val()` function, because you are multiplying `Double` values together and returning a `Double`, as shown in the code above (`As Double`).

Note: You can also use the `Return` keyword, as well as the name of the `Function` to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Need to pass the parameter values into the area function call inside totalPrice

```
Public Function area(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    area = enteredLength * enteredWidth
End Function

Public Function totalPrice(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    totalPrice = area(enteredLength, enteredWidth) * enteredPrice
End Function
```

I would also recommend changing your function parameters to `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`.  I would consider passing in the "enteredPrice" value as a parameter to the totalPrice function.